# Nginx Conditional Dynamic Proxy

Tags: nginx, websocket, proxy

I have a game running on my server.
When a user requests it, a new process on my server is started and starts to listen for a websocket connection on a random port in the range 8001-8100.

On the client i want to connect to the game.

```
var port = 8044; // <- Client is given this number when creating a new game
connection = new WebSocket("wss://XXX/websocket?port=" + port);
```

My server is a nginx reverse proxy. I want to do something like this:
(I need a working replacement for it, the below should illustrate the point.)

```
server {
...
location /websocket/ {
  if(isNumber($port) && $port <= 8100 && $port >= 8001 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$port;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
} }
```

Reason for those reverse proxy shenanigans is to be able to use the default 443 port, meaning clients won't have firewall problems. Othwerwise I would just directly connect to the correct port from the client.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `port` argument is available as `$arg_port`. It can be checked using a regular expression. For example:

```
location /websocket/ {
    if ($arg_port !~ "^80[0-9]{2}$") {
        return 403;
    }
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$arg_port;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

A little poetic licence with the port range, but a more complex expression can achieve your precise requirements. I avoid putting anything too complex inside an `if` block for [these reasons](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for more.

Comment: Unfortunately `proxy_pass http://localhost:$arg_port;` does not work. As soon as I use it instead of a number, I only receive error 502.

Comment: Hmm. It worked for me. Is there anything useful in the error log?

Comment: `no resolver defined to resolve localhost` - well, replacing it with 127.0.0.1 works. Not really sure, why localhost in combination with `$arg_port` does not work, but at least I got it running now, thank you.